# Replace Google Analytics pageview URLs with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have migrated from GA to GTM and I need know how to replace paths when sending pageviews URLs to GA. The reason is that our website has not category slugs, as example:

www.mysite.com/category-name/

While we want to track:

www.mysite.com/category/category-name/

IN GA we used to push a category slug replacing pageview URL:

ga('send', 'pageview', '');

This helped us to group together all categories. I think that we can achieve the same tracking in GTM using a Virtualpageview datalayer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dataLayer.push({
  'event':'VirtualPageview',
  'virtualPageURL':'<?php echo str_replace(get_bloginfo('url'),"/category/",get_permalink()); ?>', 'virtualPageTitle':'<?php echo the_title(); ?>'
  });
'virtualPageTitle':'<?php echo the_title(); ?>'
</script>
```

So I created a GTM "Pageviews" tag with the following "Field to set":

```
page > {{virtualPageURL}}
title > {{virtualPageTitle}}
```

This tag is triggered with a custom event "VirtualPageview". I also created 2 dataLayer variables: virtualPageTitle and virtualPageURL. However GA continue tracking categories without slugs.

I will appreciate if somebody could tell me what's wrong in my settings, or how can I replace our categories URLs in order to send category slugs to GA.

Thank you.

Comment: This answer might offer some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787881/google-analytics-and-tag-manager-support-for-custom-page-paths/41798058?noredirect=1#comment70798820_41798058. Basically you need to set the `page` field with the name of a dataLayer variable, which gets its value pushed into the dataLayer.

Comment: @nyuen Correct me if I'm wrong. I already added into Fields to Set, a field name `page` with value `{{virtualPageURL}}`. Isn't it what that answer suggests?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What are you able to see for the value of `{{virtualPageURL}}` in the GTM debug window, for the event `VirtualPageview`?

Comment: @nyuen Yes, I can see it fired in the Debug including the correct data. But Google Analytics still doesn't show my virtual category slug. You can see an example here: https://www.fanaticguitars.com/en/bass/

Comment: Are you able to send me the preview link to your container?

Comment: @nyuenI think that I fixed it. The problem was that the page value must be relative, and I was sending the full URL. After changing it, I still couldn't see it correctly because of my Chrome cookies. I checked it with Firefox and finally I saw those slugs. If you wanna check it, here is the preview link: https://www.googletagmanager.com/set_cookie?uiv2&id=GTM-NJ3NRSH&gtm_auth=IAwtE-S0-djNB8FLp7tszg&gtm_preview=env-16&gtm_debug=x&url=https://www.fanaticguitars.com/en/bass/

Comment: Yes, looks good to me. I see the pageview fire with the value of the `dp` field taken from the `virtualPageURL` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page value must be relative, and I was sending an absolute URL. After changing it, I still couldn't see it correctly because of my Chrome cookies. I checked it with Firefox and finally I saw those slugs in GA.